# Navigate to prev and next pdf file?

Tags: iphone, pdf, uiwebview

I got a pdf viewer in a uiwebview, from Daniel Barry http://github.com/danberry/PDF-Viewer and it works really well, it displays a pdf doc that you can scroll up and down.

Now I would like to display just one page at the time and also have a menu underneat the pdf page with a prev and next button. Can anybody help a newbe to figure out how?
Thanks!

```
#import "PDFViewController.h"   // PDF View Controller

@implementation PDFViewController

// Synthesize UI Element properties
@synthesize webView;
// Synthesize Variable properties
@synthesize pdfURL;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIViewController methods
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    pdfURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stuff pdf" ofType:@"pdf"]];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfURL]];
    webView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale( webView.transform, 1.00, 1.00 );
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory Management
- (void)dealloc {
    [webView release];

    [pdfURL release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a webview should show PDFs by using a default request, no need to have a new implementation?

Anyways... There are 2 methods you could check out and link to your **prev and next button**

```
- (void)goBack:(id)sender 
{
 if ([webView canGoBack]) {
  [webView goBack];
 }
}

- (void)goForward:(id)sender
{
 if ([webView canGoForward]) {
  [webView goForward];
 }
}
```

Here is the documentation of UIWebView where the methods are explained in detail: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

**EDIT**: Oh I think, I first misunderstood your question...

Just create an **Array** of the PDF URLs that you want to load. Create a **counter variable** that will hold the index value of the currently opened PDF.

And finally similar to the methods above create a **forward and backward method** and link them to the **prev and next buttons**. In those methods you **increment or decrement the counter by 1** and load the appropriate index from the array `[array objectAtIndex:counter]` so the next or previous PDF is opened.

If you need more help, let me know...

Comment: Thank you for the last line :-) 
As I have it now its just one pdf file with several pages in it, I What I have now is loaded the pdf file in the uiwebview, and I have made the prev and next buttons, and a index button that will show a chapter menu(i hope). 
If you could help me trough this I would be very happy, thanks.

Comment: ok now i get it! sorrry my native language ain't english ;)
well to navigate between the different pages I think won't be possible. Because you can not use UIWebView like a UIScrollView for example where you could read out the position of the content. I guess, you'll just have to stick with the webview as it is. Or you could divide the PDF into several PDFs (for each page one) and load those as mentioned above.

Comment: Ok, I will divide the pdf into several pdfs.
I would like to be able to load the pdf from my server, is that possible or do I have to include it from the beginning?
What next? The array? Should that be in the viewController.m file?

Comment: You can load it from a server, no problem. The webview is even going to handle the loading for you. It should go into the viewController.m probably, I don't know how your classes are laid out. Show some code...

Comment: put it as an EDIT in your question. There you can use the code functionality

Comment: I dont know how you got it with a grey background?

Comment: select the whole code and than hit the code button with the 01001 zeros and ones ;)

Answer (score 0):

ok im gonna post this as another answer...

In the header file add

```
NSArray *arrURLs;
NSInteger *currentIndex;
```

and make the array a property (retain), synthesize it in the .m file, also release it in **dealloc**.

In `- (void)viewDidLoad` initalize the array with all the URLs and set the currentIndex to 0.

```
arrUrls = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"url", @"url", ..., nil];
currentIndex = 0;
```

add two methods that you call something like **prevPage** and **nextPage** and link them to your buttons. In those methods you do something like...

```
// next page
currentIndex += 1;
NSString *str = [arrUrls objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

I would probably create another method where you set the **currentIndex** and check if it is in the correct bounds (e.g. should not be smaller than 0 and must be smaller than the length of the array). Than you can change the first line and let the method call handle the in/decrementing of the variable.

hope this helps.

Comment: if this answered your question, please select it as answer. thx

Comment: Hi jd291 I got some other thing that I had to do.
Im new at this and dont really understand it all, sorry to say, but Im learning.
With the array- if I have a 100 pdf files to display its going to be a long one :-) With the header file-I guess you mean the ViewController.m file? At the top in the ViewController.m file I added: @synthesize NSArray *arrURLs;
@synthesize NSInteger *currentIndex; and released it in dellock like this:  [NSArray release];
 [NSInteger release];
I put the array and the two methods for the buttons - (void)goBack:(id)sender... in the -(void)viewDidLoad, is this right?

Comment: i see. You are just starting  with everything. I think best would be if you zip your project upload it, post the link and i send you the correct version back ;)